# Charset in Coldfusion PDF

Tags: html, pdf, utf-8, coldfusion, character-encoding

Can someone please tell me how to fix this charset to read what I have in this pdf. Clearly something is going wrong because this information works when the file name is a .html and the coldfusion is taken out and the meta charset is utf-8. Will someone please tell me how to correct this issue I am very new to coldfusion and I believe the problem lies with my lack of knowledge. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My Result: [image]

http://jsfiddle.net/yntz3n8w/1/
What I am trying to accomplish: http://www.flhsmv.gov/dmv/forms/BTR/82040.pdf

```
    <cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="true">
    <cfcontent type="application/pdf">
    <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=test.pdf">
    <cfdocument format="PDF" localurl="yes" 
        marginTop=".25" marginLeft=".25" marginRight=".25" marginBottom=".25" 
        pageType="custom" pageWidth="8.5" pageHeight="10.2">
    <cfoutput><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>PDF Export Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>

</cfoutput>
</cfdocument>
```

Comment: Did you try to put the `<cfheader>` and `<cfcontent>` after the `<cfdcument>`?

Comment: It worked fine for me. However, if you are *hard coding* UTF-8 characters into the actual .cfm file, try using `<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8">` at the top of the script.  BTW, jsfiddle is only for javascript code. It does not run CFML code. That requires a backend CF server. For CFML snippets, try something like  http://www.trycf.com

Comment: ok thanks sorry I just wanted to show the full code and jsfiddle is the only place I knew I could

Comment: For pasting code, http://pastebin.com or http://gist.github.com are good. For runnable CF code, trycf.com. It allows *most* CF tags/functions, though not all.

Comment: According to the GOV PDF, they created it using "Adobe PDFMaker 11 for Word". Do you have HTML that replicates the exact form you want (borders, checkboxes, etc)?  If so, WKHTML2PDF (free) does a better job than CFDocument when it comes to PDF generation (pagebreaks, page numbers, custom fonts, CSS3 support). Regarding CF, which version are you using?

Comment: I am trying to duplicate that form and prefill in the fields with session variables

Comment: i attempted `<cfpdfform source="82040.pdf" action="populate"> 
    <cfpdfsubform name="form1"> 
        <cfpdfformparam name="txtfirstName" value="Harley"> 
        <cfpdfformparam name="txtlastName" value="Davidson">  
    </cfpdfsubform> 
</cfpdfform>` Just to see if something like this would work but was unsuccessful as well :/

Comment: And no i do not have html that replicates the pdf that's what Iv been spending a week trying to do and honestly feels like I am going no where just back tracking over and over and over

Comment: @Alex Leigh is pointing you in the right direction.  8+ years ago I repopulated PDF files by making PDFs in acrobat (or editting them)... inserting form fields and then manually making FDF files to hold the data to populate it with.. the cfpdfform looks like its automated now.  If your main concern is printing also look at an oldie... Coldfusion Report builder.  Its almost like building reports in MS Access.  Maybe a bit old, but 10 years later I have projects still running with it.

Comment: @Alex - Those are just sample field names. Every form is different. It will work if you use the actual field names in that pdf. See my response for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this basic order. This is how I have it in one of my files and it works OK:

```
<cfdocument format="PDF" filename="name.pdf" overwrite="Yes">
   <html>
   ...
   </html>
</cfdocument>

<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=name.pdf">
<cfcontent type="application/octet-stream" file="#expandPath('.')#\name.pdf" deletefile="Yes">
```

Comment: so header and content go at the very bottom underneath everything?

Comment: It still is all messed up doing it this way

Comment: I'm not expert on PDF files. I just posted how I have it. I think the `<cfdocument>` must be rendered before is converted to PDF. Can you verify that the data are being correctly displayed in basic HTML document? What is the source of the data? In what format are they being stored?

Comment: yes I have two files html it is fine and CF it breaks

Comment: Are those two html files `.cfm` files? Are they correctly displayed when rendered by ColdFusion as static html?

Comment: Try to change the the content type to `"application/octet-stream"` . ColdFusion recognizes the response body as text if:

the header does not specify a content type.
the content type starts with "text".
the content type starts with "message".
the content type is "application/octet-stream".

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me. However, if you are *hard coding* UTF-8 characters into the actual `.cfm` file, try using [`<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8">`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfprocessingdirective) at the top of the script. That instructs the CF engine that the contents are UTF-8 encoded, so the characters are handled correctly.

**Update:**

It sounds like your ultimate goal is to actually populate that pdf form. In which case, you probably do not need to go the hassle of recreating the whole thing in HTML and converting it to PDF. Assuming the site allows it, just grab a copy of the pdf form, and use [`cfpdfform`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfpdfform) to populate it.

Use [`<cfpdf action="read"..>`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfpdf) to get a list the various fields in the form and dump it to the screen.

```
<cfpdfform action="read" source="c:/path/to/82040.pdf" result="data" />
<cfdump var="#data#" />
```

Once you know the names of the fields you need to populate, simply use `cfpdfform` with the correct field name/value. For example, I took a quick look at that form and came up with this snippet, which populates two fields: owner name and owner email:

```
<!--- for demo purposes, display on screen ---> 
<cfpdfform action="populate" source="c:/path/to/82040.pdf">
    <cfpdfformparam name="owner name" value="John Adams"> 
    <cfpdfformparam name="owner email" value="jadams@example.com"> 
</cfpdfform>
```

Comment: Perfect Leigh is there a way to also make the form where its still fillable?

Comment: and how did you know the names of `<cfpdfformparam`

Comment: I downloaded the file and used `cfpdfform action="read"` to cfdump all of the field names. (See my updated answer). It should still be editable, as long as you do not "flatten" it.

Comment: what does "flatten" it mean?

Comment: does yours still let it be fillable mine makes it where it only fills out the formparam

Comment: by the way i wanted to say thank you I REALLY do appreciate all of your help!

Comment: That is probably due to your pdf browser plugin. If you save the pdf to disk and open it, you will see it is still "editable". *RE: what does "flatten" it mean?* Make it so the form fields are no longer "editable".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67943/discussion-between-alex-and-leigh).